# heightForRow not equal cell height in UITableView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, size

I have created a viewController which displays a plain style UITableView. Sometimes I have enough cells to fill up the table view, sometimes I don't. When I don't have enough cells I want to make the table view smaller, in order to fill the rest of the screen with a view that displays the same background color as the color of my cells.

To do that I multiply the heightForRow with the number of cells that the table view is about to display. I have set the heightForRow to 70 and I have set the height of my custom cells to 70. This does make my table view smaller than even one of my cells.

Is the tableView height calculated in a different way, or what am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The answer below did not answer my question, but it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use:

> [yourtable setTableFooterView:[[UIView alloc] init]];

Comment: Seems alright, but how can I make the height of the FooterView depend on how much "space" I got left? I mean, when I have enough cells to fill up my view, I don't want any large footer at the end.

Comment: If the rows fill up the frame allocated for the table, there shouldnt be any footer visible (or at least thats how it shows up in my table view). It only seems to have an effect when there are not enough rows to fill the frame.

Comment: Wonderful, that worked! For future reference: to make the footer view have a color, I had to set the table view background color.